# How do I tell if a function returns a Promise without executing the function?

Tags: javascript, promise

To test if an object is Promise, just inspect whether the object has a `then()` property

But what if the function is not executed, therefore the object has not produced yet. Is there a way to test? Or fake the execution? How to handle possible error from the execution then?

I'm trying to write a helper function to create action in Redux. I want to use the same interface for sync and async actions.

```
function createAction('SOMEACTION', (arg) => dosth(arg);
function createAction('FETCHACTION', (arg) =>fetch(arg);
```

I will detect the async action by checking whether `fetch()` returns a promise.

Comment: No, there's no way to do that in general. You could wrap everything in a `try`, though, if you're just looking to handle synchronous errors.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: why would you know so little about a function? If it comes from a 3rd party library, read the documentation, if it's a function you wrote, write it better - this smells a little XY problem to me

Comment: What is result for `function(){return [1, Promise.resolve()][Math.floor(Math.random()*2)];}`? How we can to know without run it?

Comment: I try to write a wrapper function to create action in redux. If the wrapped  function returns a promise, it will be diapatched

Comment: "If it looks like a duck, swims like a duck, and quacks like a duck, then it probably is a duck." :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_test

Comment: Consider the function `if(user_says_so()) return new Promise() else  return null`. You can't tell if it returns a promise without running it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I tell if a function returns a Promise

That's [impossible in general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) without executing it or by using a static type system.

> I want to use the same interface for sync and async actions.

The solution is not to detect whether a function will return a promise when called, but simply to always treat it as being asynchronous. You can use [`Promise.resolve`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) to cast eventual non-promise values:

```
function createAction(name, action) {
    …
    Promise.resolve(action()).then(result => …);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the anwser.

Answer (score 2):

A Promise is a proxy over a value, not over a process. An "IOU" if you will, for a value that will result from a running operation.

Because of that, by definition, you cannot obtain a Promise to test without first running the operation that would produce the eventual value.